# Databind XML to C# using LINQ returning one result

Tags: c#, xml, linq, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have an issue with databinding a XML document to my WP8 app. The databinding part works (I think) but only displays the top element.

XML:

```
<Application>
  <AppID>1</AppID>
  <AppID>2</AppID>
  <AppID>3</AppID>
  <AppID>4</AppID>
</Application>
```

My current c# Code:

```
    private void AddFromXML()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Resources/20Sept.xml");


        var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("Application")
                   select new AppToDownload
                   {
                       AppID = query.Element("AppID").Value
                   };

        applist.itemssource = data;
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("AppID")
                   select new AppToDownload
                   {
                       AppID = query.Value
                   };
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thankyou! Realised where I went wrong. Thanks for the near instant response!